# Run java with properties from environment variable

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm, environment-variables

In my app i need send http requests via proxy. In terminal i start it by this:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyPort=**** -Dhttp.proxyHost=***.***.***.*** -jar app.jar
```

What environment variable i should use for starting on my apps without -D options, like

```
java -jar app.jar
```

OS Linux. Java 7.

Thx!

PS already tried JAVA_OPTS, JAVA_OPTIONS, _JAVA_OPTIONS, JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has two separate ways to pass parameters to programs:

- **Properties**, which are typically specified in the command line arguments (as in your first example), loaded from files or manually added by code.
- **Environment Variables**, which are determined by settings in your operating system.

These two concepts are separate; the former doesn't affect the latter and vice versa. As such, you cannot set a property by means of an environment variable.

Other options include loading a `.properties` file during runtime (assuming your proxy hasn't already been initialized at that point) or putting the full command (`-D` arguments and all) in a shell script for easier launching.

Comment: Just an additional input, if you need to access environment variable from inside your java code, accessing it from System.getProperty(<key>) would be a better option than System.getEnv(<key>) since I found out that the getEnv was not returning the value on some machines.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is going to work with the standard Java executable.  The Java executable does not recognize any environment variables for setting *general* JVM options.

All those things that you have tried are conventions used by 3rd-party tools, scripts and launchers.

As far as I am aware, the only Java-specific environment variable that the Java executable pays attention to is `CLASSPATH`, and that is ignored when you run `java` with the `-jar` option.

---

Having said that, there is nothing<sup>1</sup> stopping you from:

- creating a wrapper script called `java` and putting it on your search path ahead of the standard `java` executable, or
- creating a shell alias called `java`.

Such a wrapper or alias could get JVM options from an environment variable, and you could call it anything you wanted to.

---

<sup>1 - ... apart from good sense :-)</sup>